# UPDATE mysql database replace strings

Tags: mysql, replace

I have in my db strings like www.domain.com and http://www.domain.com. I want to prepend to all entries the http:// but not affect other urls and as a result  have this: http://http://www.domain.com

Can this be done with mysql only? I have used REPLACE(field,'www','http://www'), but this replaces also the http://www with http://http://www

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that in the field there might be entries which don't contain www or http://www and therefore I don't want to alter or maybe there are entries like `<p><a href="www.domain.com/">domain</a></p>` in which CONCAT() prepends the http:// before `<p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `WHERE` clause to your update to only update fields that do not already have 'http://'. Test it out like this

```
 SELECT CONCAT('http://', field) FROM foo WHERE LOCATE('http://', field)=0
```

and your `UPDATE` syntax would be:

```
UPDATE foo SET field=CONCAT('http://',field) WHERE LOCATE('http://', field)=0
```

Comment: +1, [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) is also another viable option.

Answer (score 0):

I won't worry about performance as this seems like a one-off kind of script. That said, you can couple [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to achieve this:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     mycolumn = CONCAT('http://',mycolumn)
WHERE   LEFT(mycolumn,7) <> 'http://'
```

Do note that I'm not taking CapItaliZation in to account. You may also want to consider sanitizing the information either before adding it to the database, or maybe make a trigger to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Search and Replace Query - mysql replace

Here is the SQL query to replace string in your MySQL database table:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name,'original_string','replace_string')
```

Here is what I did to change the path URLs in all my previous posts.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'http://localhost/','https://sureshkamal1.wordpress.com/')
```

Comment: Why no `WHERE`? Is this too much superfluous? Does it cost anything to add something like `WHERE column_name LIKE CONCAT('%s', 'original_string', '%')`? I wonder…